# Работа с моделью в виде(view)

Tags: yii2, yii, php, mysql

Активируется контроллер Index:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    return $this->render('index');
}
```

Далее, в view происходит выборка данных:

```
use app\models\Manuals;

    foreach(Manuals::find()->all() as $manual)
    {
        $authors = $manual->getAuthors()->all();
        echo $manual['title_'.Yii::$app->language].'___['.$manual['type'].']';
        foreach($authors as $author)
        {
            echo ' - '.$author['fio_'.Yii::$app->language];
        }
        echo '<br>';
    }
```

Всё работает и хорошо даже, это мне посоветовали на форуме, но, мне кажется, Вид(view) не должен вообще иметь никаких дел с моделью, ему дают данные - он их прорисовывает, но не выбирает.

Переместить этот код в контроллер - не могу, т.к.:

```
foreach(Manuals::find()->all() as $manual)
```

не работает, если задать вот так:

```
foreach($manuals as $manual)
```

где $**manuals** - это уже выбранные данные через контроллер.

А не работает, потому что:

```
$authors = $manual->getAuthors()->all();
```

Ошибка, функция не определена, когда я выборку в контроллере делаю и в **foreach** передаю уже объект.

Comment: > кажеться

тся тся тся тся тся тся

> прорисовует

прорисовывает

> Вид(view) не должен вообще не иметь никаких дел с моделью

Он может получить уже готовую модель/коллекцию, но с выборкой действительно его ничего не должно связывать (по возможности). В частности, здесь у модели должны быть методы вроде getTranslatedTitle($language), getTranslatedFullName($language). Что до getAuthors()->all(), то оно конечно не очень хорошо, но приемлимо.

> Переместить этот код в контроллер - не могу

Код перемещать не нужно, нужно перемещать выборку и скармливать $manuals во view.

Answer (score 2):

```
Manuals::find()->all()
```

Перемещаем в контроллёр и выбираем сразу с авторами с помощью жадной загрузки (будет всего 2 запроса) (если этого не сделать, то кол-во запросов будет равным 1 + count($manuals) )
В контроллёре код:

```
Manuals::find()->with(['authors'])->all()
```

Во вьюхе код:

```
foreach($manuals as $manual)
{
    ...
    foreach($manual->authors as $author)
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Плюс, можете выбрать в виде массива, будет супер-круто по ресурсозатратам:

```
Manuals::find()->with(['authors'])->asArray()->all()
```